# Set state in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have an application with 3 inputs: name, percentage, and password. Also, I have a save button that should change the state, using the values from the inputs, in the parent component.

Using Ant Desing, I want to set the percentage, but I can't get the `[e.target.name]` from the Input Number from AntD.

How to solve this, and when I click the save button to update the state in parent component?.

code link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ytowzg

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question itself. If you need to use an off-site resource for others to run your code that's perfectly fine, but try to always accompany it with some code in the question too. It makes it easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some notice points:

- setState inside handler `onInputNumber()`
- since the component is fully controlled, you don't need `defaultValue`
- add `value={state.percentage}` props instead.
- add `percentage` inside `save()`

Try it online: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-5qrwcq

```
const Test = ({ user, setUser }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ name: "", password: "", percentage: "1" });

  function onChange(e) {
    setState({
      ...state,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
    console.log(state)

  }
  function onInputNumber(value) {
    setState({...state, percentage: value})
    console.log('changed', value);
  }

  function save() {
    setUser({ ...user, name: state.name, password: state.password, percentage: state.percentage });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input name='name' onChange={onChange} />
      <input name='password' onChange={onChange} />
      <InputNumber
      // defaultValue={100}
      min={0}
      max={100}
      value={state.percentage}
      formatter={value => `${value}%`}
      parser={value => value.replace('%', '')}
      onChange={onInputNumber}
    />
      <button onClick={save}>save</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the name from the onchange of the Antd input.

```
 <InputNumber
      defaultValue={100}
      min={0}
      max={100}
      formatter={value => `${value}%`}
      parser={value => value.replace('%', '')}
      onChange={(value) => onInputNumber('myinput', value)}
    />


function onInputNumber(name, value) {
    console.log('changed', value, name);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your save function, it appears that you haven't coded the update to percentage:

```
function save() {
    setUser({ ...user, name: state.name, password: state.password });
  }
```

Hope this helps.